# Was there a symbol for negative one?

Tags: math-history, constants

This may be more of a historical math question.

In any old, ancient, or even modern symbolism; was there a symbol or letter that represented the value $-1$?

This goes in pair with how ancient mathematicians would commonly use a symbol for $0$ before the concept of zero was well defined.

Comment: Any other related tags would also be useful

Comment: For what it's worth, some formattings in excel (and probably other spreadsheet software) use $\color{red}{1}$ (a $1$ coloured red) as the negative of $1$.

Comment: @Arthur ah, that's interesting. I wonder why that is.

Comment: I think it aligns with standard business phrases regarding the color red as signifying deficit and black signifying surplus. I don't any more than that, though.

Comment: @Arthur It was once standard accounting practice, to use red ink to denote a negative number (i.e. a loss).  Thus the common idioms "in the red" vs "in the black".

Comment: For *zero*, see [Zero: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0#History).

Comment: Actually red for negative numbers is relatively new. The ancient Chinese knew negative numbers, but they did the contrary: https://nrich.maths.org/5961 Well, red is the lucky color in China.

Comment: Not sure if this counts towards what you're looking for but in modern notation, $-1\equiv a-1\mod a$ so, e.g. $-1\equiv 9\mod 10$.

Comment: there is a separate history of math and science stack exchange: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$-1$ has not had any special symbols in widespread use. It was "minus" that has had various symbols for its representation both to negate a quantity and/or as subtraction operation (some of them are $m^\circ$, *meno*, $m\tilde e$, $men$, $\tilde{m}$, $\sim$, $^{\cdot}\hspace{-6pt}{-}$, $\div$, and many others).
There are lots of books on this subject.

There is just one exception in what I've just said. In 1925 the mathematician J. P. Ballantine had a similar intuition as yours. In American Mathematical Monthly Vol. 32 No. 6 (Jun.-Jul. 1925) p.302 he wrote:

> Mathematical historians will tell you how many years mathematics was held back for want of a digit $0$. Though not comparing in importance with that digit, there is a certain advantage in having a digit to represent negative one.

He continues proposing the adoption for $-1$ of a symbol which is $1$ rotated by $180^\circ$ around its center (in mathjax its difficult to represent; it is something like $\downharpoonright$. In Latex it is much more simple using this syntax: \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{1}, after having imported the graphics package with \usepackage{graphicx})

Please note that Ballantine proposes such a symbol not for the number $-1$ but for $-1$ as a digit.

In this way not only it is possible to write $${\downharpoonright}\times2=-2$$ but it is also possible to write: $${\downharpoonright}.123=-1+0.123$$ $${\downharpoonright}0=-10$$ $${\downharpoonright}2=-10+2$$ with $${\downharpoonright}2={\downharpoonright}92=...={\downharpoonright}99992=...$$

In the end Ballantine's proposal as himself says it is a way to represent numbers in their tens' complement representation.

---

**EDIT:**

Ballantine does not give an example of numbers where the digit $\downharpoonright$ is not the most significant digit, probably because he does not need such sofistication in his intended application (that is, to complement a given positive number $x$ w.r.t. an integer $n$-th power of ten, where $n\ge\log_{10} x$ ). Anyway following his philosophy we could also write:
$${\downharpoonright}{\downharpoonright}=-11$$
$$10.{\downharpoonright}=10-0.1$$

That said, Ballantine originality is mainly about the new symbol proposed for the digit $-1$. As to the applications it is not as much as original. Think that the periodical editor recalls in a footnote (*Op. cit.*) that a generalization coud be one in which digits $\bar5, \bar4, \bar3, \bar2, \bar1, 0,1,2,3,4,5$ are used instead of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ for real number encoding, where $\bar5=-5,...$
Indeed this was something very well known in past centuries. As early as 1726 John Colson in "A Short Account of Negativo-Affirmative Arithmetick" *Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London* Vol 34 pp. 161-173 introduces such negative figures, as he calls them, as a means to ease arithmetic especially when large numbers are involved. It is no more than tens' complement encoding of numbers.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! One question: if ${\downharpoonright}2=-10+2$, wouldn't it be more consistent if ${\downharpoonright}.123=-1+0.123=-0.877$? Which option does Ballantine prefer?

Comment: @ChrisCulter you caught me! :-) It's my error. Thanks. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: Very interesting. It begs the question what other numbers would be such as $⇂⇂$ or $10.⇂$.

Comment: @Graviton see edit

Comment: If only I could upvote twice

Comment: @Graviton your appreciation is better than upvotes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In balanced ternary, there is a symbol for negative one.
If T is negative one, then in balanced ternary, you count
0000,
0001,
001T,
0010,
0011,
01TT,
01T0,
01T1,
etc